# Finding integer solutions to $\sqrt{a+b^2+c^3}=a-b-c$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb Z$ and $a\ne b\ne c$

Tags: equation-solving, diophantine-equations

So I want to use Mathematica to find integer solutions to the following Diophantine equation$$\sqrt{a+b^2+c^3}=a-b-c$$with$$a,b,c\in\mathbb Z\qquad a\gt b\gt c$$<strike>I have managed to find a solution on my own with `\sqrt{6+2^2+1^3}=\sqrt{6+4-1}=\sqrt{10-1}=\sqrt9=6-2-1=3`</strike> Nope, the solution I found by hand was incorrect, however I want to try finding solutions using Mathematica since finding all of the solutions by hand would be really difficult.

[Using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF084.png)

```
FindInstance[Sqrt[a+b^2+c^3]==a-b-c&&a!=b!=c,{a,b,c},Integers,20]
```

I got a single solution:

```
{{a->0,b->1,c->-1}}
```

[image]

<sup>I know I didn't state the `ClearAll` function that I had used in the first line, however please ignore that as I was only using it to ensure that it wasn't just a bug with my notebook</sup>

[I then tried using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YjHMO.png) (current code)

```
Solve[Sqrt[a+b^2+c^3]==a-b-c&&a!=b!=c,{a,b,c},Integers]
```

and while this did give me 3 new solutions, only one of them satisfied my conditions:

```
{a->-3,b->-2,c->-1}
{a->0,b->1,c->-1}
{a->3,b->1,c->0}
```

[image]

So my question is: How can I improve my code to make sure that I can attain all of the solutions to the Diophantine equation$$\sqrt{a+b^2+c^3}=a-b-c\qquad a,b,c\in\mathbb Z\qquad a\gt b\gt c$$

Comment: is your equation $\sqrt{a+b^2+c^3}=a-b-c$ or $\sqrt{a+b^2+c^3}=a-b^2-c$? Your proposed solution does not solve the former, only the latter...

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform oh crap I must've wrote it incorrectly, I'll fix it

Comment: your solution is still wrong, it reads $\sqrt{6+2^2+1^3}=\sqrt{6+4\color{red}{+}1}=\sqrt{10+1}=\sqrt{11}\neq6-2-1=3$

Comment: Your title says a!=b!=c. Your description says a>b>c. I'll let you figure that out. `t=Partition[Flatten[Table[{a,b,c},{c,-100,100},{b,c+1,100},{a,b+1,100}]],3];
Select[t,({a,b,c}=#;Sqrt[a+b^2+c^3]==a-b-c)&]` finds 96 solutions and that hints to me that there are more

Comment: @Bill That's because I hadn't figured out how to implement that

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I must've done the math incorrectly on that tbh

Comment: `t=Tuples[Range[-60,60],3];
r=Select[t,({a,b,c}=#;Sqrt[a+b^2+c^3]==a-b-c&& a!=b&&a!=c&&b!=c)&]`

Comment: Just as a side remark: calling `ClearAll` without any arguments doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With changing the condition a!=b!=c to a>b>c we get:

```
Solve[Sqrt[a + b^2 + c^3] == a - b - c && a > b > c, {a, b, 
  c}, Integers]
```

[image]

And if we un-iconize the condition:

[image]

Therefore, if the conditions are fulfilled, a has the value:

```
1/2 (1 + 2 b + 2 c) + 1/2 Sqrt[1 + 4 b + 4 b^2 + 4 c + 4 c^3]
```

The condition for b and c is fulfilled for multiple values of b and c. To get e.g. 10 of them:

```
sol=FindInstance[((1/2 (1 + 2 b + 2 c) + 
        1/2 Sqrt[1 + 4 b + 4 b^2 + 4 c + 4 c^3] | b | c) \[Element] 
     Integers && b > -(1/2) + 1/2 Sqrt[1 + 4 c^2 - 4 c^3] && 
    c <= -1) || ((1/2 (1 + 2 b + 2 c) + 
        1/2 Sqrt[1 + 4 b + 4 b^2 + 4 c + 4 c^3] | b | c) \[Element] 
     Integers && c >= 0 && b > c), {b, c}, 10]

{b -> 1, c -> 0}, {b -> 37, c -> 0}, {b -> 943, c -> 0}, {b -> 812, 
  c -> 0}, {b -> 587, c -> 0}, {b -> 834, c -> 0}, {b -> 71, 
  c -> 0}, {b -> 2, c -> 0}, {b -> 456, c -> 0}, {b -> 757, c -> 0}}
```

To check these:

```
Sqrt[a + b^2 + c^3] == a - b - c /. 
  a -> 1/2 (1 + 2 b + 2 c) + 
    1/2 Sqrt[1 + 4 b + 4 b^2 + 4 c + 4 c^3] /. sol

{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
```

Answer (score 6):

Alternative without `Sqrt`

```
FindInstance[a + b^2 + c^3 == (a - b - c)^2 && 100 > a > b > c > -100, {a, b,c}, Integers, 100]
(*{{a -> 31, b -> 21, c -> -6}, {a -> 50, b -> 41, c -> -11},
```

{a ->37,b -> 18, c -> 0}, {a -> 63, b -> 31, c -> 0},
{a -> 7, b -> 3,c -> 0}, {a -> 12, b -> 8, c -> -3},
{a -> 75, b -> 37,c -> 0}, {a -> 50, b -> 11, c -> 9},
{a -> 43, b -> 28,c -> -7}, {a -> 28, b -> 22, c -> -7},...}*)

finds all 96 solutions (see Bill's comment)

Answer (score 6):

Note that, from the given Equation, we must have the condition $a - b - c \geqslant 0$. I consider $1\leqslant a,b,c\leqslant 100$.

```
 {a, b, c} /. 
 Solve[{(a + b^2 + c^3) == (a - b - c)^2, 
   a - b - c >= 0, (a - b) (b - c) (c - a) != 0, 1 <= a <= 100, 
   1 <= b <= 100, 1 <= c <= 100}, {a, b, c}, Integers]
```

> {{7, 1, 2}, {12, 4, 2}, {18, 1, 5}, {18, 6, 3}, {21, 6, 4}, {31, 10,
> 5}, {32, 5, 7}, {33, 14, 3}, {42, 12, 7}, {43, 15, 6}, {48, 13,
> 8}, {50, 11, 9}, {57, 21, 7}, {70, 31, 5}, {72, 15, 12}, {72, 19,
> 11}, {72, 33, 4}, {73, 28, 8}, {77, 32, 7}, {78, 15, 13}, {80, 35,
> 6}, {91, 36, 9}, {96, 1, 18}, {98, 29, 13}, {99, 33, 12}}

[image]